# Using svcutil.exe to generate identical namespace as Add Service Reference

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I have a WCF service and when I add a reference to it using VS.NET 2012 via the `Add Service Reference...` option, I specify a namespace, in the bottom of the dialog (i.e. `MyNameSpace')

This generates the following 1st few lines of code in the auto generated `Reference.cs` class:

```
namespace MyProject.MyNameSpace {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System;

//Lots of auto generated proxy class code...

}
```

The problem is when I use the `svcutil.exe` utility to generate the proxy classes manually, I don't get that namespace and I get a *ton* of the following error when building:

> The type or namespace name 'MyNameSpace' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'MyProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

So I tried the following (2) things and neither worked:

1. Manually add a simple `namespace MyProject.MyNameSpace {}` declaration around the generated `Reference.cs` class from the `svcutil.exe` utility.
2. Use the `/n` 'Namespace' switch in `svcutil.exe` with the following: `/n:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNameSpace,MyNameSpace` which did not work and produced the following:

   using System.Data;

   [assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyNameSpace", ClrNamespace="MyNameSpace")]

Ok, that did not work either and added a namespace declaration attribute of sorts, but not a `namespace` wrapper as before.

How can I make it so when generating the proxy class using `svcutil.exe`, the identical `namespace` is added to the generated class, so when plugged back into my project, everything builds as expected?

**EDIT:** Using the following namespace switch I got the desired namespace but a *duplicate* declaration in my methods which is causing another issue:

Namespace: `/n:*,MyProject.MyNameSpace`
Example Issue in Proxy now: `public bool MyMethod(MyProject.MyNameSpace.MyProject.MyNameSpace.MyRecord record)`

Notice the *repeat* in the namespace; it's a problem.

Comment: I think the `/n:*,MyProject.MyNamespace` is the way to go.  A couple questions...  Are you generating from a URL?  If so, could you download the file and try locally, and attach here to take a look or at least post add the part for MyMethod?What attributes are on the generated methods, i.e. MyMethod?  One note, are you sure you are capitalizing correctly?  Namespace is a single word and the `s` shouldn't be capitalized, but if it is everywhere it shouldn't be a problem.